# Monotouch WCF - Bindings supported?

Tags: wcf, binding, xamarin.ios

Using Monotouch and WCF.

Is there a list of supported bindings?

In test we are able to use BasicHttpBindings and want to know for production what bindings are supported.

Example:

```
svc = new TimesheetServiceClient (new BasicHttpBinding (), new EndpointAddress (SomeURL));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MonoTouch supports the same WCF bindings as the Silverlight 3 client profile which is limited to BasicHttpBinding at this time.  If you have any issues with BasicHttpBinding please file bugs with testcases and we'll be certain to fix them.

Comment: Great. We'll let the architects know what their options are.